# Pass content from Angular app to a library

Tags: angular

Okay, so I'm way out of my depth here (I'm new to development)...

I am trying to pass some content (a set of hyperlinks) from my Angular application to a library which it uses. The library is one that I created and is installed via NPM and contains a sidebar which will hold the list of links which will act as the navigation around the app. I will create the links in the app-routing.module within the app.

How do I go about passing that information to the library and displaying it within the sidebar component?

Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: Is the only purpose of your library to display some links ?

Comment: If so, consider making an Angular component for that, a libray is way too overkill.

Comment: You could expose a service from the library that your FE will inject into a component. Then call a method that uses a `subject` to update the values in the library.